# How to Inspect Cookies in Safari 11 Developer Requests & Responses?

Tags: cookies, safari

This must have been answered somewhere but I just cannot find the answer - how can I inspect the cookies set in http `RESPONSE` and `REQUEST` in Safari 11?

I am looking for something similar to Chrome DevTools Network tab inspector where you can see any cookies sent, per http request/response, and what they contained.

I've tried inspecting the cookies via `Storage` but even here some cookies are present, others not. What is weird is that I can see cookies set by third parties like Stripe or Intercom, but not the cookies associated with the actual domain I am on. All these cookies are present and being set in Chrome & Firefox.

Thank you!